# In ethers.js how to deal wait()?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

In ethers.js,

```
provider.sendTransaction(rawTransaction).then((transaction) => {
    // A full Transaction Response is returned
    // - from
    // - to
    // - gasLimit, gasPrice
    // - nonce
    // - r, s, v
    // - wait() => Promise that resolves the Transaction Receipt once mined
    //             and rejects with an error is the stats is 0; the error
    //             will have a transactionHash property as well as a
    //             transaction property.

    let hash = transaction.hash;
});
```

Here it will return the receipt after `wait()` how can I write the wait in my code?

I use:

```
.then(function(tx){
wait()=>{}
｝）
```

This will not work.

Answer (score 8):

```
const sendTransaction = async() => {
    const transaction = await provider.sendTransaction(rawTransaction);
    // wait() has the logic to return receipt once the transaction is mined
    const receipt = await wait(transaction);
}
```

In this way you can write a wait in your code.

Answer (score 7):

For ethers.js v5:

```
let receipt = await tx.wait()
```

Answer (score 6):

Either like this:

```
wait().then(function(receipt) {
    // do whatever you wanna do with `receipt`
});
```

Or like this if you call the whole thing from inside an `async` function:

```
const receipt = await wait();
// do whatever you wanna do with `receipt`
```